# Binding (get: set) method of class doesn't update value in View

Tags: swift, swiftui

Value of Binding(get: set) in Stepper (realized by method of class) doesn't updates in ForEach-cycle in View. I want to take values from array.

I think, that it updates if I refresh View by some another way.
What can be wrong with function? View shoud be updated when I click on Stepper.
Simple version of my code is bellow.

UPD: the task is to change the value by a function (method in class) (to achieve a high level of abstraction in the code). Not bind it directly like `$item.item`

Thank you!

```
import SwiftUI

class IntegerItem: ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var item: Int
    init(item: Int) {
        self.item = item
    }
    
    func bindFunc() -> Binding<Int> {
        let bindingVar = Binding (
            get: { self.item },
            set: { self.item = $0 } )
        return bindingVar
    }
}

var array: [IntegerItem] = [IntegerItem(item: 1), IntegerItem(item: 2), IntegerItem(item: 3)]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = array
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach($items, id: \.id) {$item in
                Stepper("item value is \(item.item)", value: item.bindFunc())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove that function and use `value: $item.item` directly

Comment: Thank you @burnsi for your answer!, You are right, if use '$item.item' directly it will work. But its simple version of code. But the task is to change the value by a function (to achieve a high level of abstraction in the code)

Comment: Thats that kind of information that should have been included in your question. And you really need to put more information out here. You are doing multiple things in a way thats not common(e.g. using classes for models etc.). It will be hard for us to help you without more context.

Comment: @burnsi, thanks for your advice, I've updated my question (sorry, I'm new here ).
I'm using a class for the model because I need a Reference type of variable. 
I'm afraid that, if I write here more code can confuse.

Comment: The structure you've chosen (storing an array of `ObservableObject`s inside a `@State` variable) is pretty unusual for SwiftUI and will lead to unexpected results like you have. Instead, make `IntegerItem` a `struct` and get rid of the `bindingFunc` and `@Published` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you back on track:

```
import SwiftUI

class IntegerItemStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [IntegerItem(item: 1), IntegerItem(item: 2), IntegerItem(item: 3)]

    static let shared = IntegerItemStore()
}

struct IntegerItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var item: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var store = IntegerItemStore.shared

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach($store.items) { $item in
                Stepper("item value is \(item.item)", value: $item.item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```